# Linearization of a function in the point 0, 0

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

The linearization of the function $ f(x, y) = 1 + 2(x + 1) + 3(y + 1) + 4x^2 + 5y^2  $ in the point (0, 0) is given by:

$ L(x, y) = 6 + 2x + 3y $

I know this is true, but how does one come to this conclusion ?

Thanks a lot in advance, this is not homework, this is an attempt to learn it for an exam, so an elaborative explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: Why did you label this linear algebra?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Taylor's theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) to determine the first order polynomial
\begin{align}
L(x,y) &= f(0,0) + f_x(0,0)\, x + f_y(0,0) \, y \\
&= 6 + (2+8x)\rvert_{(x,y)=(0,0)} \, x +  (3+10y)\rvert_{(x,y)=(0,0)} \, y\\
&= 6 + 2x + 3y
\end{align}

Comment: Using Taylor sorry ?

Comment: I added a link.